# Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.set(int, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy tratando de editar un objeto que se muestra en una **ListView** y cuyos datos están guardados en **Firebase**. El objeto es de tipo *Medicina* y cuenta con dos propiedades de tipo String: *nombre y dosis*.

Actualmente consigo eliminar los elementos de la *listview*, y a la hora de editarlos conseguir que se muestren los valores de sus parámetros antiguos. Sin embargo, a la hora de guardar los nuevos valores para sus parámetros dosis y nombre, se produce el error que he indicado en el título de esta pregunta.

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.set(int, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

Layouts:

**A) item_medicina_xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">




        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medicamentoNombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:text="nombre"

         />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medicamentoDosis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:text="dosis"

        />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/iconoEditMedicina"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round"

        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/iconoDeleteMedicina"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iconoEditMedicina">

            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

---

**B) input_box_medicine_edit.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtmessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMediNameInput"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"

            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMediDosisInput"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btMediAct"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Actualizar"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

---

**C) activity_modified_medicine.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/add_new_medicine_modified"
        android:hint="Escribe el nombre del medicamento"

        ></EditText>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/add_new_dosis_medicine"
        android:hint="Escribe su dosis"

        ></EditText>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Añadir medicamento"
        android:id="@+id/btnAñadirMedicinaModified"></Button>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMedicines"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Y el código de la **activity AddMedicineModified.java**:

```
public class AddMedicineModified extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AddNewMedicine";
//declaro las variables
    private Button mAddToDB;
    private EditText mnombre;
    private EditText mdosis;

    //variables relacionadas con Firebase: para guardar los datos asociados al determinado usuario logueado, etc
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private DatabaseReference puntoDeAcceso;
    private  String userID;

    //Para que se vean los datos de firebase del usuario
    //
    private List<Medicina> medicinas;
    private List<String> list;
    private MedicinaAdapter medicinaAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ChildEventListener childEventListener;

    //Declarar las imágenes ImageView de delete y edit

    private ImageButton mEditView;
    private ImageButton mDeleteView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modified_medicine);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMedicines);

        //MedicinaAdapter con layout creado y lista vacía
        final List<Medicina> medicinas = new ArrayList<>();
        medicinaAdapter = new MedicinaAdapter(this, R.layout.item_medicina, medicinas);
        mListView.setAdapter(medicinaAdapter);








        mAddToDB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAñadirMedicinaModified);
        mnombre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_new_medicine_modified);
        mdosis=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_new_dosis_medicine);



       //Firebase
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        myRef=myRef.child("Medicamentos");

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        //puntoDeAcceso=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Medicamentos").child(userID);
        puntoDeAcceso=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");


        //esto para ver si está bien logeado
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    toastMessage("Has iniciado sesión con: " + user.getEmail());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    toastMessage("Has cerrado bien sesión.");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };





        mAddToDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String newMedicine= mnombre.getText().toString();
                String newDosis=mdosis.getText().toString();
                Medicina medicine=new Medicina(newMedicine,newDosis);
                puntoDeAcceso.push().setValue(medicine);

                toastMessage("Añadiendo " + newMedicine + " a la base de datos...");



            }

        });

        puntoDeAcceso.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if (s != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                }
                //Creo un objeto mensaje
                Medicina mensaje = dataSnapshot.getValue(Medicina.class);
                //y se lo añado al adapter
                medicinaAdapter.add(mensaje);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //voy a intentar hacer el delete aquí
                //ImageButton mDeleteView=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iconoDeleteMedicina);

            }






            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });






    }
    public void showInputBox(Medicina oldItem, final int index){
        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(AddMedicineModified.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Input Box");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_box_medicine_edit);
        TextView txtMessage=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
        txtMessage.setText("Edite el objeto");
        txtMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff2222"));
        //esto es para que salga un mensaje que indique al usuario qué tiene que hacer


        //esto para que recupere los valores antiguos
        EditText editTextName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMediNameInput);
        EditText editTextDosis=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMediDosisInput);
        editTextName.setText(oldItem.getNombre());
        editTextDosis.setText(oldItem.getDosis());

        final Medicina updatedMedicina=new Medicina(editTextName.getText().toString(),editTextDosis.getText().toString());
        final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");

        Button bt=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btMediAct);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                medicinas.set(index,updatedMedicina);//error aquí
                db.child("Nombre").setValue(updatedMedicina.getNombre().toString());
                db.child("Dosis").setValue(updatedMedicina.getDosis().toString());
                medicinaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }




    class MedicinaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Medicina> {

        Context context;
        List<Medicina> medicinas;

        public MedicinaAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,
                              @NonNull List<Medicina> medicinas) {
            super(context, resource, medicinas);
            this.context=context;
            this.medicinas=medicinas;

        }

        public int getCount(){
            return medicinas.size();
        }

        public Medicina getItem(int pos) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getMedicinaId(int pos) {
            return pos;


        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            //Para el objeto i-ésimo recupero el elemento de la lista contenedora
            Medicina medicina=medicinas.get(i);
            //Recupero el "inflador" de layouts
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater().from(context);
            //Inflo el layout item_message que he definido
            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_medicina,viewGroup,false);

            //Recupero los componentes del item_message
            TextView nombre=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoNombre);
            TextView dosis=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoDosis);


            //Le asigno los valores del mensaje
            nombre.setText(medicina.getNombre());
            dosis.setText(medicina.getDosis());

            //Inicializamos ImageViews
            ImageButton mEditView;
            mEditView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoEditMedicina);
            ImageButton mDeleteView;
            mDeleteView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoDeleteMedicina);

            mEditView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showInputBox(medicinas.get(i),i);
                }
            });


            mDeleteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Medicina medicinaBorrar=medicinas.get(i);
                    final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");
                    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                Medicina medicamento=snapshot.getValue(Medicina.class);
                                if (medicinaBorrar.getNombre().equals(medicamento.getNombre())){
                                    db.child(snapshot.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                                    medicinas.remove(i);
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    /*medicinas.remove(i);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();*/ //esto funciona para quitar de listview pero no de firebase
                }
            });

            //Devuelvo la vista que he creado
            return view;
        }





    }









    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

---

Y la clase **Medicina.java**:

```
public class Medicina {

    String nombre;
    String dosis;

    //constructores
    public Medicina(){

    }

    public Medicina(String nombre, String dosis){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.dosis=dosis;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }
    public String getDosis(){
        return dosis;
    }

    public void setDosis(String dosis){
        this.dosis=dosis;
    }
}
```

**¿Cómo puedo solucionar este fallo?** No entiendo por qué se está produciendo, **¿Quizás debo inicializar antes el objeto updatedMedicina?**

El stack del error es el siguiente:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.gstiandroidaplicacion, PID: 16591
>           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.set(int, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>               at com.example.gstiandroidaplicacion.AddMedicineModified$4.onClick(AddMedicineModified.java:219)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
>               at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
>               at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

Comment: Puedes compartir el stack de error completo?

Comment: Tienes un poco de lío con las variables `medicinas`. Defines una en la clase de la Activity, y luego otra en onCreate. Y no la rellenas cuando obtienes los datos de la base de datos, ni cuando creas una medicina nueva, pero luego la usas donde dices que te falla. Igual la excepción es por eso. Has probado a depurar poniendo un punto de ruptura ahí y comprobando que hay en la lista?

Comment: @solamente Acabo de añadirlo

Comment: @SuperG280 Acabo de darme cuenta de lo de la variable medicinas, de lo que estaba repetida. Cuando dices que no la relleno cuando obtengo los datos de la base de datos, ¿a qué parte del código te refieres? Siento la pregunta quizás algo absurda pero soy bastante novato en java y android.

Comment: El atributo `private List<Medicina> medicinas` de la clase `AddMedicineModified` no está inicializado (es null), lo que provoca esa NPE.

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando pulsas el botón para añadir haces el push a la base de datos pero no lo añades a tu lista

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que veo el problema esta en el `onCreate()`:

```
   //Aquí creas una nueva variable LOCAL con el mismo nombre de tu variable GLOBAL
     final List<Medicina> medicinas = new ArrayList<>();
```

_

```
// Lo que tienes que hacer es inicializar la variable correcta de esta forma
// tu variable GLOBAL será la que se cargue en tu MedicinaAdapter.
// evitando el mensaje de null cundo la uses en otro método.
 this.medicinas = new ArrayList<>();
 medicinaAdapter = new MedicinaAdapter(this, R.layout.item_medicina, medicinas);
 mListView.setAdapter(medicinaAdapter);
```

Es una buena practica llamar a tus variables GLOBALES (las que se declaran en la clase y son accesible por cualquier método de esta por ejemplo `private List<Medicina> medicinas;`) con `this.medicinas`, de esta forma estas seguro que la variable es de tipo GLOBAL y no una variable LOCAL que has creado en el método y tenga el mismo nombre.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he solucionado gracias a los consejos dados anteriormente y que agradezco. Lo único que falta es arreglar la actualización en Firebase del objeto, pero se ve actualizado en el listview al menos. El código de AddMedicineModified es finalmente el siguiente:

```
public class AddMedicineModified extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AddNewMedicine";
    //declaro las variables
    private Button mAddToDB;
    private EditText mnombre;
    private EditText mdosis;

    //variables relacionadas con Firebase: para guardar los datos asociados al determinado usuario logueado, etc
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private DatabaseReference puntoDeAcceso;
    private  String userID;

    //Para que se vean los datos de firebase del usuario
    //
    //private List<Medicina> medicinas;

    private MedicinaAdapter medicinaAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ChildEventListener childEventListener;

    //Declarar las imágenes ImageView de delete y edit

    private ImageButton mEditView;
    private ImageButton mDeleteView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modified_medicine);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMedicines);

        //MedicinaAdapter con layout creado y lista vacía
        List<Medicina> medicinas = new ArrayList<>();
        medicinaAdapter = new MedicinaAdapter(this, R.layout.item_medicina, medicinas);
        mListView.setAdapter(medicinaAdapter);








        mAddToDB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAñadirMedicinaModified);
        mnombre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_new_medicine_modified);
        mdosis=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_new_dosis_medicine);



        //Firebase
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        myRef=myRef.child("Medicamentos");

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        //puntoDeAcceso=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Medicamentos").child(userID);
        puntoDeAcceso=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");


        //esto para ver si está bien logeado
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    toastMessage("Has iniciado sesión con: " + user.getEmail());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    toastMessage("Has cerrado bien sesión.");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };





        mAddToDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String newMedicine= mnombre.getText().toString();
                String newDosis=mdosis.getText().toString();
                Medicina medicine=new Medicina(newMedicine,newDosis);
                puntoDeAcceso.push().setValue(medicine);

                toastMessage("Añadiendo " + newMedicine + " a la base de datos...");



            }

        });

        childEventListener=new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                //Si he recuperado un objeto lo muestro en el Log
                if(s!=null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                }
                //Creo un objeto mensaje
                Medicina medicina=dataSnapshot.getValue(Medicina.class);
                //y se lo añado al adapter
                medicinaAdapter.add(medicina);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        puntoDeAcceso.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);







    }





    class MedicinaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Medicina> {

        Context context;
        List<Medicina> medicamentos;

        public MedicinaAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,
                               @NonNull List<Medicina> medicamentos) {
            super(context, resource, medicamentos);
            this.context=context;
            this.medicamentos=medicamentos;

        }

        public int getCount(){
            return medicamentos.size();
        }

        public Medicina getItem(int pos) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getMedicinaId(int pos) {
            return pos;


        }

        public void showInputBox(Medicina oldItem, final int index){//el edit no está creando un objeto medicina y por eso falla
            final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(AddMedicineModified.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Input Box");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_box_medicine_edit);
            TextView txtMessage=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
            txtMessage.setText("Edite el objeto");
            txtMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff2222"));
            //esto es para que salga un mensaje que indique al usuario qué tiene que hacer


            //esto para que recupere los valores antiguos
            final EditText editTextName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMediNameInput);
            final EditText editTextDosis=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMediDosisInput);
            editTextName.setText(oldItem.getNombre());
            editTextDosis.setText(oldItem.getDosis());

            //no se puede crear una nueva medicina

            final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");
            //hay que guardar los datos en la key del objeto recogido

            Button bt=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btMediAct);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {//ahora mismo se crea una nueva medicina
                    medicamentos.get(index).setNombre(editTextName.getText().toString());
                    medicamentos.get(index).setDosis(editTextDosis.getText().toString());
                    //Con esto actualiza en la ListView pero no en la Firebase

                    medicinaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    toastMessage("Objeto editado");
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            //Para el objeto i-ésimo recupero el elemento de la lista contenedora
            Medicina medicina=medicamentos.get(i);
            //Recupero el "inflador" de layouts
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater().from(context);
            //Inflo el layout item_message que he definido
            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_medicina,viewGroup,false);

            //Recupero los componentes del item_message
            TextView nombre=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoNombre);
            TextView dosis=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoDosis);


            //Le asigno los valores del mensaje
            nombre.setText(medicina.getNombre());
            dosis.setText(medicina.getDosis());

            //Inicializamos ImageViews
            ImageButton mEditView;
            mEditView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoEditMedicina);
            ImageButton mDeleteView;
            mDeleteView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoDeleteMedicina);

            mEditView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showInputBox(medicamentos.get(i),i);
                }
            });


            mDeleteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//funciona bien
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Medicina medicinaBorrar=medicamentos.get(i);
                    final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");
                    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                Medicina medicamento=snapshot.getValue(Medicina.class);
                                if (medicinaBorrar.getNombre().equals(medicamento.getNombre())){
                                    db.child(snapshot.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                                    medicamentos.remove(i);
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    toastMessage("Objeto eliminado");
                                    break;

                                }
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    /*medicinas.remove(i);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();*/ //esto funciona para quitar de listview pero no de firebase
                }
            });

            //Devuelvo la vista que he creado
            return view;
        }





    }









    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```